# mySQL Failed and Recovered

Tags: mysql

For some reason mySQL keeps failing and recovering through the day. We have increased max database connections from 150 to 200, but that was not the problem and did not solve the issue.

Does anyone have familiarity as to why this might be happening?

Service Name:   mysql
Service Status: failed
Notification:   The service “mysql” appears to be down.
Service Check Method:   The system’s command to check or to restart this service failed.
Number of Restart Attempts: 1
Startup Log:

Starting MySQL. SUCCESS!

Log Messages:

```
150607 22:24:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/domain.com.pid ended

150607 22:24:29 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted

150607 22:24:29 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0

2015-06-07 19:49:59 7779 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.

150607 19:49:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

150607 19:49:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/domain.com.pid ended

2015-06-07 19:49:35 6304 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2015-06-07 19:49:34 6304 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 184  user: 'modsec'

2015-06-07 19:49:34 6304 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 6  user: 'eximstats'

2015-06-07 19:49:32 6304 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2015-06-07 19:25:25 6304 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Memory Information:

```
Used: 717 MB
Available: 254 MB
Installed: 972 MB
```

Load Information:   8.71 4.02 1.68
Uptime: 8 days, 6 hours, 52 minutes, and 46 seconds

IOStat Information:

```
vg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.41    0.18    0.72    0.11    0.18   93.40
Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
vda              34.92      1098.70       333.56  786957034  238914332
```

Comment: Off-topic because it doesn't appear to be a programming problem. [dba.se] would probably be a better place to ask.

Comment: Find and show the error log.

Comment: Can we please vote to close this question. User seems to have deleted themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You have less than 1GB of RAM?  If so, you need to be very frugal with the configuration.

```
max_connections = 50 -- not 200
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M -- if using InnoDB; else 0
key_buffer_size = 30M
```

Did you change other settings in `my.cnf`?